# Why is my data being changed going from a frontend form submit to a backend API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, prisma

I'm having an issue in Next.js 13 and Prisma. I have a basic form created to send user information to an api. If I print the submitted data in the event handler right before it's sent, everything is fine. When I print the data as soon as it arrives to the backend it shows that the order of the contents was changed, one string was changed to undefined, and another's value was changed to "String". I switched to axios thinking it could be an issue with serialization, but that didn't work either. I'll include the detailed error log at the bottom.

Here is my Register.tsx form:

```
"use client"
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

 export default function Register() {
    // States to store user input
    const [user, setUser] = useState({
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        eMail: '',
        confirmEmail: '',
        passWord: '',
        confirmPassword: ''
    })
     
    // State to store response from API
    const [response, setResponse] = useState('');
     
    // Event handler for input changes
    const handleInputChange = (e: { target: { name: string; value: string; }; }) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        setUser((user) => ({
            ...user,
            [name]: value
        }))
     };

    // Event handler for form submission
    const handleSubmit = async (e: { preventDefault: () => void; }) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (user.eMail !== user.confirmEmail) {
            setResponse("Emails must match")
        }

        if (user.passWord !== user.confirmPassword) {
            setResponse("Passwords must match")
        }

        if (user.passWord == user.confirmPassword && user.eMail == user.confirmEmail) {
            try {
                const response = await axios.post('/api/register/', {
                    fname: user.firstName,
                    lname: user.lastName,
                    email: user.eMail,
                    password: user.passWord
                });

                // const response = await fetch('/api/register/', {
                //   method: 'POST',
                //   headers: {
                //     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                //     },
                //   body: JSON.stringify({
                //     fname: firstName,
                //     lname: lastName,
                //     email: eMail,
                //     password: passWord
                //   }),
                // })

                if (response) {
                    setResponse("Check email for verification.");
                } else {
                    setResponse("Error with registration.");
                }
                
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('API request failed', error);
                setResponse('Error: Failed to connect.');
            }
        }
    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <div className="grid gap-6 mb-6 md:grid-cols-2">
                {/* First name field */}
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="firstName" className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">First name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" value={user.firstName} onChange={handleSubmit} className="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500" placeholder="Steph" required>
                    </input>
                </div>

                {/* Last name field */}
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="lastName" className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Last name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" value={user.lastName} onChange={handleSubmit} className="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500" placeholder="Xalo" required>
                    </input>
                </div> 

                {/* Email field */}
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="eMail" className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" name="eMail" id="eMail" value={user.eMail} onChange={handleSubmit} className="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500" placeholder="steph@xalo.com" required>
                    </input>
                </div>

                {/* Confirm email field */}
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="confirmEmail" className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Confirm email</label>
                    <input type="email" name="confirmEmail" id="confirmEmail" value={user.confirmEmail} onChange={handleSubmit} className="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500" placeholder="steph@xalo.com" required>
                    </input>
                </div>

                {/* Password field */}
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="passWord" className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="passWord" id="passWord" value={user.passWord} onChange={handleSubmit} className="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500" placeholder="•••••••••" required>
                    </input>
                </div>

                {/* Confirm password field */}
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="confirmPassword" className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Confirm password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="confirmPassword" id="confirmPassword" value={user.confirmPassword} onChange={handleSubmit} className="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500" placeholder="•••••••••" required>
                    </input>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="flex items-start mb-6">
                <div className="flex items-center h-5">
                <input id="remember" type="checkbox" value="" className="w-4 h-4 border border-gray-300 rounded bg-gray-50 focus:ring-3 focus:ring-blue-300 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:focus:ring-blue-600 dark:ring-offset-gray-800" required>
                </input>
                </div>
                <label htmlFor="remember" className="ml-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300">I agree with the <a href="#" className="text-blue-600 hover:underline dark:text-blue-500">terms and conditions</a>.</label>
            </div>

            <button type="submit" className="text-white bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm w-full sm:w-auto px-5 py-2.5 text-center dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-800">Submit</button>
            <div className="flex justify-center">
                <p className="text-white">{response}</p>
            </div>
        </form>
    )
}
```

Here is my route.ts form:

```
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

const prisma = new PrismaClient({
  errorFormat: 'pretty',
})

interface User {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

export async function POST(req: Request) {
  // pull information from request
  const { firstName, lastName, email, password }: User = await req.json();

  console.log(firstName);
  console.log(lastName);
  console.log(email);

  // generate salt and hash password
  
  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
  const hashed = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
  
  // use prisma to query database, insert new user
  try {
    const register = await prisma.user.create({
      data: {
        fname: firstName,
        lname: lastName,
        email: email,
        password: hashed,
      },
    });

    if (!register) {
      return Response.json({ error: "There was an error during registration. Please try again." });
    } else {
      return Response.json({ message: "User successfully registered." });
    }
      
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error registering user:', error);
    return Response.json({ error: "Internal server error." });
  } finally {
      // always disconnect
      await prisma.$disconnect();
  }
}
```

```
PS C:\Users\Stephan\Desktop\hipro\frontend> npm run dev

> frontend@0.1.0 dev
> next dev

  ▲ Next.js 13.5.4
  - Local:        http://localhost:3000
  - Environments: .env

 ✓ Ready in 3.4s


Source path: C:\Users\Stephan\Desktop\hipro\frontend\src\app\globals.css
Setting up new context...
Finding changed files: 44.334ms
Reading changed files: 207.297ms
Sorting candidates: 8.125ms
Generate rules: 288.555ms
Build stylesheet: 3.595ms
Potential classes:  10394
Active contexts:  1
JIT TOTAL: 698.988ms


 ✓ Compiled /page in 2.2s (747 modules)


Source path: C:\Users\Stephan\Desktop\hipro\frontend\src\app\globals.css
Finding changed files: 35.396ms
Reading changed files: 0.052ms
Sorting candidates: 0.008ms
Generate rules: 0.31ms
Build stylesheet: 0.004ms
Potential classes:  1
Active contexts:  1
JIT TOTAL: 62.281ms


 ✓ Compiled in 352ms (242 modules)
 ✓ Compiled /registration/page in 846ms (867 modules)
 ⚠ Fast Refresh had to perform a full reload. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/fast-refresh-reload
 ✓ Compiled /api/register/route in 129ms (598 modules)
  prisma:tryLoadEnv  Environment variables loaded from C:\Users\Stephan\Desktop\hipro\frontend\.env +0ms
  prisma:client  checkPlatformCaching:postinstall undefined +0ms
  prisma:client  checkPlatformCaching:ciName undefined +0ms
  prisma:tryLoadEnv  Environment variables loaded from C:\Users\Stephan\Desktop\hipro\frontend\.env +3ms
  prisma:client  dirname C:\Users\Stephan\Desktop\hipro\frontend\node_modules\.prisma\client +0ms
  prisma:client  relativePath ../../../prisma +0ms
  prisma:client  cwd C:\Users\Stephan\Desktop\hipro\frontend\prisma +0ms
  prisma:client  clientVersion 5.4.2 +1ms
  prisma:client:libraryEngine  internalSetup +0ms
  prisma:client:engines:resolveEnginePath  enginePath C:\Users\Stephan\Desktop\hipro\frontend\node_modules\.prisma\client\query_engine-windows.dll.node +0ms
undefined
undefined
johnwick@wick.com
  prisma:client:libraryEngine  library starting +65ms
  prisma:client:libraryEngine  library started +29ms
  prisma:client  Prisma Client call: +97ms
  prisma:client  prisma.user.create({
  data: {
    fname: undefined,
    lname: undefined,
    email: "johnwick@wick.com",
    password: "$2b$10$C9qzC1KY4zA2KnAxRorNrulwpS2keSpxNSiZu.jB6BdF3RBM.kA0S"
  }
}) +0ms
  prisma:client  Generated request: +1ms
  prisma:client  {
  "modelName": "User",
  "action": "createOne",
  "query": {
    "arguments": {
      "data": {
        "email": "johnwick@wick.com",
        "password": "$2b$10$C9qzC1KY4zA2KnAxRorNrulwpS2keSpxNSiZu.jB6BdF3RBM.kA0S"
      }
    },
    "selection": {
      "$composites": true,
      "$scalars": true
    }
  }
}
 +0ms
  prisma:client:libraryEngine  sending request, this.libraryStarted: true +4ms
  prisma:client:request_handler  PrismaClientKnownRequestError: Unable to match input value to any allowed input type for the field. Parse errors: [`data.fname`: A value is required but not set, `data.fname`: A value is required but not set]
    at Zt (C:\Users\Stephan\Desktop\hipro\frontend\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:36:253)
    at mr.buildQueryError (C:\Users\Stephan\Desktop\hipro\frontend\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:115:1216)
    at mr.request (C:\Users\Stephan\Desktop\hipro\frontend\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:114:4091)
    at async Object.singleLoader (C:\Users\Stephan\Desktop\hipro\frontend\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:123:5333)
    at async Cn.request (C:\Users\Stephan\Desktop\hipro\frontend\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:123:5825)
    at async l (C:\Users\Stephan\Desktop\hipro\frontend\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:128:9968)
    at async POST (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/app/api/register/route.ts:26:26)
    at async C:\Users\Stephan\Desktop\hipro\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:62361 {
  code: 'P2009',
  clientVersion: '5.4.2',
  meta: { kind: 'Union', errors: [ [Object], [Object] ] }
} +0ms
Error registering user: PrismaClientValidationError: 
Invalid `prisma.user.create()` invocation:

{
  data: {
    lname: undefined,
    email: "johnwick@wick.com",
    password: "$2b$10$C9qzC1KY4zA2KnAxRorNrulwpS2keSpxNSiZu.jB6BdF3RBM.kA0S",
+   fname: String
  }
}

Argument `fname` is missing.
    at En (C:\Users\Stephan\Desktop\hipro\frontend\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:116:5888)
    at Cn.handleRequestError (C:\Users\Stephan\Desktop\hipro\frontend\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:123:6516)
    at Cn.handleAndLogRequestError (C:\Users\Stephan\Desktop\hipro\frontend\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:123:6206)
    at Cn.request (C:\Users\Stephan\Desktop\hipro\frontend\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:123:5926)
    at async l (C:\Users\Stephan\Desktop\hipro\frontend\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:128:9968)
    at async POST (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/app/api/register/route.ts:26:26)
    at async C:\Users\Stephan\Desktop\hipro\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:62361 {
  clientVersion: '5.4.2'
}
  prisma:client:libraryEngine  library stopping +19ms
  prisma:client:libraryEngine  library stopped +0ms
```

Comment: It looks like req.json has eg `fname` and not `firstname`

Answer (score 1):

The error is related to the mismatch between the names of the fields in your frontend form and the fields in your backend.

Update your frontend code and then boom it worked.

```
const response = await axios.post('/api/register/', {
    firstName: user.firstName,
    lastName: user.lastName,
    email: user.eMail,
    password: user.passWord
});
```